# Textbox should not to allow spaces in asp.net using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, .net

Textbox should not allow the spaces in it. I have written a java script which is working..But it failed when space bar is pressed continuously. 
Please suggest.
Code i used given below :

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function splitText() 
{
var fullNumber = $get('<%= tbFullNumber.TextBoxClientID %>').value;        
$get('<%= tbFullNumber.TextBoxClientID %>').value = fullNumber.replace(' ', '');
fullNumber = $get('<%= tbFullNumber.TextBoxClientID %>').value;
}
```

Comment: `But it failed when ...` <= please define `failed` (how does it `fail`)?

Comment: when it pressed single space its not allowing ...When we press space button continuously pressed down(keep our finger for a while)  it accepting spaces..when removed it's removing only the last space.remaining spaces are existing in text box.

Answer (score 0):

I'd re-design the scripts to have it replace all spaces at once when the control loses focus. Slap a "spaces will be removed" bold label beside the textbox and you're golden.

This way, it doesn't matter how the input is made (do users type? do they copy-paste? do they keep buttons pressed ? do they use on-screen keyboard ? do they ...).

AFAIK two events are attached to this, `onfocusout` (when the control is about to lose focus but hasn't yet) and `onblur`(when the control has lost focus). You can of course handle both.

Replacing all spaces in a string is easy:

```
theString = theStringreplace(/\s/ig,''); // '  b  l ah  ' = 'blah'
```

Comment: can i write two events for one text box Ex: onblur and lastfocus ? if yes how can i remove spaces from middle of the text as wel as right and left at a time with script.

Comment: Edited to include specifics about the implementation. Be sure to flag as accepted if it works, to aid future <eaders in recognizing the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that much code to prevent this type of scenario ... have a look in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7pvmx2t7/1/) ... Do something like this ..

HTML

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="handleSpace(event)"  />
```

JavaScript

```
function handleSpace(event) 
{
  //handling ie and other browser keycode 
  var keyPressed= event.which || event.keyCode;

  //Handling whitespace
  //keycode of space is 32
  if(keyPressed==32)
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```